# Flutter : how to fetch data and manage app state

Tags: flutter

I'm trying Flutter and I need (I think I do) an app state management to share datas across widgets and dont have to make an http request each time a route is called.

I have Places and Events, so I first load my Places to list them at creation of app state with :

```js
void main() {
  runApp(
    ChangeNotifierProvider(
      create: (context) => AppStateModel()..fetchPlaces(),
      ...
    )
  );
}
```

When I click on a Place, I go on place/id screen and as Places doesnt have events props yet, I'm trying to load them with :

```js
class PlacePageArguments {
  final String id;

  PlacePageArguments(this.id);
}

class PlacePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const PlacePage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<PlacePage> createState() => _PlacePageState();
}

class _PlacePageState extends State<PlacePage> {
  String id = '';

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final args =
        ModalRoute.of(context)!.settings.arguments as PlacePageArguments;

    return Consumer<AppStateModel>(builder: (context, appState, child) {
      id = args.id;
      appState.fetchEvents(id);
      final place = appState.getPlaceById(id);

      return Scaffold(...);
    })
  }
}
```

But for sure, as I notifyChange to update widget, It does an infinite loop on fetch events.

What should I do ?
What is the best to achieve something like that, maybe a simple futurBuilder will work, but I want to add events and stay on the same page (add event with modal) and want instant result.

thanks for all

Comment: https://flutter.dev/docs/development/data-and-backend/state-mgmt/options

Comment: I've found this page, that's why I used provider...

Answer (score 0):

You have two options for bringing in the data for this and none of them require ChangeNotifierProvider.

1. You can pass data via constructors. This works fine for small widget trees but it can easily get complicated.
2. You can use Providers. Providers allow you to manage data and functions in one class that stays in one file. For more deals please look [here](https://pub.dev/packages/provider).

Comment: Thanks. I think I cant pass data via constructor, because my widget will evolve in live. I have a list, a button "add" that display an alert form, so the list is still visible in back. And if I add an object to this list, I want the list to display it instantly. So if I use a classic provider and don't notify, how my list will be refreshed ?

Comment: Use a ChangeNotifierProvider, this will allow you to call notifyListeners() which will as it suggests, notifies listeners, thus allowing you to instantly update.